# i get undefined variable error when pass controller to view Undefined variable: users (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\site\resources\views\edit.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel, variables, undefined

//here is my controller

```
public function edituser(Request $request,$id){

    $user=User::find($id);
    $user->name=$request->name;
    $user->email=$request->email;
    $user->role_id=$request->role_id;

    $users=User::all();

    return view('edit',compact('users'));
}
```

//here is blade

```
<form action="{{route('edituser',['id'=>$user->id])}}" method="post">
@csrf
    <div class="form-row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-auto">
            <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInput">Adı</label>
            <input type="text" value="" class="form-control mb-2" id="inlineFormInput" placeholder="Adı">
        </div>

        <div class="col-auto">
            <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroup">Emaili</label>
                <div class="input-group mb-2">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup" placeholder="Emaili">
                </div>
        </div>


        <select class="mdb-select md-form">
            @foreach ($users as $user)
            <option>--Səlahiyyət seç---</option>
            <option value="1">{{$user->name}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
```

//here is route

```
Route::get('edit/{id}','AdminController@edit')->name('edit');
Route::post('edituser/{id}','AdminController@edituser')->name('edituser');
```

Update: here is my all controller

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\User;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class AdminController extends Controller
{


    public function delete($id){

        $delete=User::where('id',$id)->delete();

        if($delete){

                return redirect()-> back();
        }
    }


public function edit(){


        $users=User::all();

    return view('edit',compact('users'));
}

public function edituser(Request $request,$id){

        $user=User::find($id);
       $user->name=$request->name;
       $user->email=$request->email;
       $user->role_id=$request->role_id;

}
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and paste your `AdminController@edit` method? Does it use the same view?

Comment: On which line you get this error here?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are using the wrong method on the controller.
The `edituser` method is used by the POST route, so you should have users/compact code on the `edit` method instead, as that is being used by the GET route.

Move the following code from `edituser` and put it into `edit`

```
$users = User::all();

return view('edit',compact('users'));
```

Your `edituser` method should probably look like:

```
public function edituser(Request $request,$id){

    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->name=$request->name;
    $user->email=$request->email;
    $user->role_id=$request->role_id;

    return view('edit',compact('user'));
}
```

Please update your original answer to show both methods.

Comment: i cut this code ( $users=User::all();

return view('edit',compact('users')); and paste in edit method but it give same error

Comment: Please update the question and add the entire controller, so we can help you better. At the bottom of your question, put in `UPDATE: --Insert code--`

Comment: it work but it cant work in form and in selects. why? and why  i cant use $users  in form in selects with use foreach? so i cant use it loop for select options

Answer (score 0):

```
public function edit($id) {
    $user = User::find($id);
    $users = User::all();
    return view('edit')->with(compact('user', 'users'));
}


public function edituser(Request $request, $id) {
    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->name = $request->name;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->role_id = $request->role_id;

    $users = User::all();
    return view('edit')->with(compact('user', 'users'));
}
```

Hope fully it will help to you easily.

Comment: i cant use $user variable in form(select options). Why? Do you know it?

Comment: $user single object not a array

Comment: <select class="selectpicker form-control" id="user_id" 
                                    data-live-search="true" 
                                    name="user_id" data-width="100%" data-size="10"  
                                    data-title="Select User">
                                @foreach($users as $val)
                                <option value="{{$val['id']}}">
                                    {{$val['name']}}     
                                </option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>

Comment: or i cant use $users array with foreach in form.  why? when used it give me undefined variable error

Comment: i solve it. thank  you. it give error because i call $user before i initialize foreach loops.